# Difference between namespace in XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

I'm creating XML document using XDocument in C#.
I have a question.

Is

```
<Simple xmlns = "Example"></Simple>
```

equivalent to

```
<Example:Simple></Example:Simple>
```

?

I tried to get second solution with XNamespace and XElement in C#, but I get only first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

The first example creates a *Simple* element in the Example namespace (note that namespaces are usually expressed as URIs)

The second example creates a *Simple* element in whatever namespace is associated with the Example prefix (as defined by an `xmlns` attribute).

These would be equivalent:

```
<xml xmlns="http://example.com/myNameSpace">
    <Simple></Simple>
</xml>

<xml xmlns="http://example.com/myNameSpace" xmlns:Example="http://example.com/myNameSpace">
    <Example:Simple></Example:Simple>
</xml>
```

Comment: Namespaces are **always** expressed as URI-references. They're usually expressed as absolute URI-references rather than relative as in the question, so they don't change meaning.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you have defined a *default* namespace which applies to any element/attribute that is not prefixed with its own namespace.

In the second example, you have not defined a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

No, because xml namespaces allow for characters which aren't supported by element names, you can't prefix an element tag name with its namespace like that.

Add a namespace prefix, like so:

```
<alias:Simple xmlns:alias = "Example"></alias:Simple>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, but it's equivalent to:

```
<Example:Simple xmlns:Example="Example"></Example:Simple>
```

It's a bad idea to use relative URIs as the namespace name, since this XML now has a different namespace depending on where it came from. So always give the full URI. E.g if the XML was being received from `http://example.net/somePlace/someXML` then the relative URI `Example` expands to `http://example.net/somePlace/Example`, so use it fully:

```
<Example:Simple xmlns:Example="http://example.net/somePlace/Example"></Example:Simple>
```

OR

```
<Simple xmlns="http://example.net/somePlace/Example"></Simple>
```

Otherwise if someone saved it in `C:\Documents` then on opening it again it becomes the equivalent to:

```
<Simple xmlns="file:///C|/Documents/Example"></Simple>
```

Which means that the meaning of `Simple` here is completely different to that when it was first downloaded.